# If $S,T$ are finite sets and there is injective and not surjective function $f: S \to T$ so there is no injective function : $g: T \to S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that, if $S,T$ are finite sets and there is a injective and not surjective function $f: S \to T$ then there is no injective function $g: T \to S$.

**My proof :**

There is an injective and not surjective function $f: S \to T$ $\implies |S|\leq |T|$.

Suppose there an is injective function :

$g: T \to S \implies |T|\leq |S|$.

$|T|=|S|$ (this follow from the Cantor-Bernstein theorem).

$|T|=|S| \implies$ there is bijection $F: S \to T $.

Use :

> Let n∈N and let f:{1,…,n}→{1,…,n} be a function. Then f is injective
> iff f is surjective.

Contradiction!

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to show that if you have two finite sets $S$ and $T$ that any injective function $f:S\to T$ is surjective?

Comment: @Saegusa No , i try to show if i have non-surjective and injective function $f:S\to T$ then there is no injective function $f:T\to S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach:

For a set $A$ with a finite number of elements, let $|A|$ denote the number of elements in $A$.

Since $S$ and $T$ are finite sets, and $f$ is injective, the number of elements in the image of $f$ must equal the number of elements in $S$.

Since $f$ is not surjective, there must be an element in $T$ that is not in the image of $f$.  Therefore $|T|$ must be strictly greater than $|S|$.

Consider the function $g : T \to S.$  Since $|T| > |S|$, there must be a situation where $g$ is mapping two different elements $t_1, t_2 \in T$, to the same element $s \in S.$  Therefore, $g$ can not be injective.